# Redshift union with date column filter error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a table `t` with date column `d` in Redshift.

I can run a simple select query with a filter on `d` such as:

```
select *
from t
where d = '2022-02-01'::date
```

The above also runs for `2022-01-01` and other dates.

However, if I try to run a query with a union of filtered dates like:

```
select *
from t
where d = '2022-02-01'::date
union
select *
from t
where d = '2022-01-01'::date
```

I get the error:

```
[42846] ERROR: could not convert type "unknown" to numeric because of modifier
```

Removing the `where` condition filter in the union above actually runs without problems. Column `d` values are all valid dates with no nulls.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Try wrapping the subqueries in brackets. It might be trying to apply the WHERE to the final result, rather than the individual select. `(SELECT ... WHERE ... ) UNION (SELECT ... WHERE ...)`

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I've tried that but it doesn't work either.